# UCanAccess "cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: ms-access, ucanaccess

The below code for getting Connection from Microsoft Access File Filename.accdb by using Ucanaccess Jdbc Driver. But while running this code it throw exception like File already being used.

But I want to use a MSAccess Database File concurrent while it is in use by other application as well.

```
      //Code for connecting with MS Access Database
            public void getConnection(){
               Connection connection = null;
               Statement statement = null;
               ResultSet resultSet = null;
                    try {
                        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {
                        logger.error("Problem in loading or "
                                + "registering MS Access JDBC driver " + cnfex);
                    }

                    String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + msAccDB;
                    logger.info("DB File Url = " + msAccDB);
                    try {
                        DriverManager.registerDriver(new UcanaccessDriver());
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        logger.error(ex);
                    }
                    return connection;
            }
```

And while i run the above code got the exception like :

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.x.x E:\FileName.accdb (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
>                   at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:231)
>                   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>                   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
>                   ................................................................
>                   ...............................................................
>                   ...............................................................
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>                   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
>                   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>                   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>                   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>                   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>               Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\Retail Expert Data\Pos.accdb (The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process)
>                   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
>                   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
>                   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
>                   at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.openChannel(DatabaseImpl.java:489)
>                   at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.impl.DatabaseImpl.open(DatabaseImpl.java:381)
>                   at com.healthmarketscience.jackcess.DatabaseBuilder.open(DatabaseBuilder.java:252)
>                   at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DefaultJackcessOpener.open(DefaultJackcessOpener.java:35)
>                   at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReference.(DBReference.java:169)
>                   at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.DBReferenceSingleton.loadReference(DBReferenceSingleton.java:51)
>                   at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver.connect(UcanaccessDriver.java:90)
>                   ... 17 more

Answer (score 0):

For this type of scenario, it is better to migrate up to SQL server which handles multi-user access significantly better (safer, faster) than Access while generally retaining compatible data structures.

Comment: Thanks! But i need to integrate with 3rd Party Application which may be 6 to 7 year old. And they might be not interested to upgrade their system. So I need to figure out from my side. So is there any other solution please share.

Comment: Understood. I have run into the same thing. If you find an answer, please post update here.

Answer (score 0):

The other application has performed an "Open Exclusive" on the database file. Therefore, no other process can open the database concurrently.

If you want to have both applications accessing the database simultaneously you will need to have the other application open the database in non-exclusive mode. Also, be aware of the limitations described in this blog post:

[Multiuser concurrent write access](http://ucanaccess.blogspot.ca/2017/07/multiuser-concurrent-write-access.html)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the Microsoft Access application is split - with a front end file linking to the back end tables.  Then copy the front end file for your own exclusive use.

In a multi user set up of Access - it must be split and every user must have their own front end file.

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested me to work with C# Dot Net. And I tried to access MSAccess Database Surprisingly It works with [OleDBConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples) while the Microsoft Access File is in use with other Application and also file opened.

**checkout the solution**

If we use Another language like C#.

It is definitely possible to access the  Ms-access Database File while it's being used by another application as well.

```
public static OleDbConnection GetMSAccessDatabaseConnection(){

// If accdb file password ecrypted 
string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file_path + ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" + your_password + ";";

// Without password
string ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file_path + ";Persist Security Info=False;";                

try{
        return new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
    }
catch(Exception ex){
     // Log your Exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to be surprised, Access databases can be used by multiple processes, however it is not well supported in UCanaccess

Answer (score 0):

UCanAccess does not support that. It needs exclusive access to the database file.

https://ucanaccess.blogspot.com/2017/07/multiuser-concurrent-write-access.html

In my experience, as long as you don't update the database via UCanAccess, the databasefile will not be corrupted. No guarantees, though ...

You can use the jdbc-odbc-bridge instead. You can google how to migrate the bridge from Java 7 to Java 8 so you can use all the cool java 8 features, and you can also configure odbc in Wine so that your java application can run on Linux with a Windows jre/jdk that support jdbc-odbc-bridge. However, as the database file resides on a "E:" drive I assume you use Windows, so you don't need Wine.

If the opposite is the case you can also set up a generic Docker container with Wine, windows-java and odbc configured so that you can easily spin up a container running a jar file and access database file from the host file system. It is somewhat slow but works just fine, except debugging, which is VERY slow.

Here is what I plan to do to resolve a similar problem. It is pretty ugly (yes, really, really, really ugly), but it is only temporarily and will allow a step-by-step transition away from Microsoft Access and to a jdbc-supported database, without having to run stuff on Windows:

I will start out with UCanAccess and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.ttddyy</groupId>
        <artifactId>datasource-proxy</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then I will intercept all jdbc-statements using ProxyDataSourceBuilder and QueryTransformer (from datasource-proxy, on github the usage is explained). All selects will be allowed to pass through untouched, but create, update and delete will be intercepted, I will "resolve" all query parameters manually (all the ? in the parameterized query), and pass the string on to a file, or a rest-api, where a Windows-java service running in Wine can pick it up and execute it via odbc and Access database engine. Then I'll just throw some exception to prevent UCanAccess from actually writing to the Access database file. Hibernate will make a lot of fuss about failed optimistic locking but any exceptions can be caught so that the actual application can proceed.

OBVIOUSLY this is NOT how to do it in a production environment AT ALL, but if it proves somewhat "stable" I can just get by until migration away from Access is complete, without setting up a Windows development environment in VMWare, or running the applications on Windows at all. This is clearly a don't-try-this-at-home-kids kind of stunt, but my app has no concurrent users, no need for speed, no overly important data that can't be restored from backup, and so on, so I figured I'd give it a try.